# How to add several users to Item using SPservices

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

How can I add many users to Item with multiple users, using SPservices? Is it possible in JQuery?

I have next jquery:

```
//Users ID, who shoud be located in the field "Users"
var us1 = 110; 
var us2 = 113;
var uw3 = 115;


$().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        batchCmd: "Update",
        listName: "testList",
        valuepairs: [["users", us1]],
        ID: 5, 
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
             alert("yeah, ready!");
    });
}
```

Now the field ["users"] had type "Multiple Users" and this method adds only one user (us1).
So, how can I add to field ["users"] several users (us1, us2, us3)?

Comment: *I mean, "add many users to Item with multiple users in Sharepoint 2010"

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow tends to work best when you can post something you've tried that others can take a look at it and make suggestions.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm newbie there, and will try to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the question is a year old, but I found it and it was without an answer, so: for updating user field with multiple choices (adding and removing a user)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">

function UpdateParticipants(listName, itemId, userName, userId, initialData) {

    var usersToSet = "";
    if (!IsStringEmpty(initialData)) {
        usersToSet = initialData + ";#" + userId + ";#" + userName;
    } else {
        usersToSet = userId + ";#" + userName;
    }

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        debug: true,
        listName: listName,
        ID: itemId,
        valuepairs: [["EventParticipants", usersToSet]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if (Status != "success") {
                alert("Something Went Wrong. You haven't applied for the event, please contact Event Manager.");
            } else {
                alert("You have succesfully applied for the event.");
            }
        }
    });

}

function RemoveParticipant(listName, itemId, userName, userId, initialData) {

    var usersToDelete = userId + ";#" + userName;
    var usersToSet = initialData.replace(usersToDelete, "");

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        async: false,
        debug: true,
        listName: listName,
        ID: itemId,
        valuepairs: [["EventParticipants", usersToSet]],
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            if (Status != "success") {
                alert("Something Went Wrong. You haven't resigned from the event, please contact Event Manager.");
            } else {
                alert("You have succesfully resigned from the event.");
            }
        }
    });

}

function IsStringEmpty(inputString) {
    if (inputString != null && inputString != "" && inputString != "undefined" && inputString.length > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

  
</script>
```

listName - is is, in fact, list GUID in my case... :)